# How do I get the status code OK response from a gRPC client

Tags: python, grpc

Im trying to get the status code from the client in gRPC when the response is successful with python. Similar to REST API when you do `response.status_code == 200`. I need to assert that is a successful call

I've tried unpacking the response by doing. This is the code structure, not the actual one

```
reposonse, metadata, code = stub.{Mygrpc}(request, metada)

print(code)
```

but what I only need is to get the status code in Python.

```
response = onboarding_stub.AnswerEmailChallenge(request=answer_email_request,
                                                    metadata=[('authorization', get_token)])
```

I would like to see the grpc.Status_code.OK display in console from that call. I don't know which function from which package to use to get the status code.

Answer (score 10):

A `grpc.RpcError` is raised to indicate non-OK grpc status code. You can catch the exception to print status code.

```
try:
    response = onboarding_stub.AnswerEmailChallenge(request=answer_email_request,
        metadata=[('authorization', get_token)])
except grpc.RpcError as e:
    print(e.code())
else:
    print(grpc.StatusCode.OK)
```

Comment: if there is no error, you should use `call.code()`. this implies that you use `with_call` to make the request.