# How to use grpc status code and build response accordingly to the client?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am wondering what is the best way to deal with grpc status code and response when we sent back to the user?

```golang
func (us *customerService) FetchResponse(ctx context.Context, request *custPbV1.CustomerRequest) (*custPbV1.CustomerResponse, error) {
    meta := service.MetadataFromContext(ctx)
    clientId := meta.ClientId
    if clientId <= 0 {
        msg := fmt.Sprintf("could not retrieve client info for clientId:%d", clientId)
        // is this right way to return it?
        return nil, status.Error(codes.NotFound, msg)
    }

    resources := request.GetResources()
    if len(resources) == 0 {
        // is this right way to return it?
        err := status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "value cannot be null. (Parameter 'resources')")
        return nil, err
    }

    return us.GenerateCustomerInfo(clientId, resources)
}
```

My proto is very simple -

```proto
service CustomerService {
   rpc FetchResponse(CustomerRequest) returns (CustomerResponse) {};
}

message CustomerRequest {
   string resources = 1;
}

message CustomerResponse {
   string proc = 1;
   string data = 2;
}
```

`GenerateCustomerInfo` method will return `CustomerResponse` and `error` both. But if there is a error then what status code it will be? I am trying to figure out what is the standard basically people follow while returning grpc status code and response back to user. Is it mandatory to return status code back to client or no?

Is it good idea to have error property in response object as well? Any example that demonstrates best practice on how to return grpc status and response back will be useful for me.

Comment: where is the `err` variable defined in the go code ? what could make the first if to be accessed ?

Comment: @ClémentJean Sorry fixed that. It was a copy paste mistake.

Comment: if you have any other question let me know, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally fine to do it like this:

```golang
err := status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "value cannot be null. (Parameter 'resources')")
return nil, err
```

This will tell your client that there is an error and with that knowledge the client can check the status code and the status message as following:

```golang
resp, err = server.FetchResponse(context.Background(), req)
s, ok := status.FromError(err)

if ok { // there is an error
   fmt.Printf("Code: %d, Message: %s\n", s.Code(), s.Message())
}
```

> GenerateCustomerInfo method will return CustomerResponse and error both. But if there is a error then what status code it will be?

For the `GenerateCustomerInfo` we don't have much info to reproduce but in my opinion you should just return something like:

```golang
return &custPbV1.CustomerResponse{
    Proc: "YOUR_PROC",
    Data: "YOUR_DATA",
}, nil
```

by returning `nil` in the error, you will show the client that there is no error and in the previous code give the `ok` will be false.

> Is it good idea to have error property in response object as well?

for that, you definitely could add an error property, but is there any need for that? you can already have a StatusCode and a Message. It would just increase the size of your payload unnecessarily.

> But if GenerateCustomerInfo return any error then what status code should I return back? Do I need to define that too?

Given an potential implementation of `GenerateCustomerInfo` like:

```golang
func GenerateCustomerInfo() (*pb.CustomerResponse, error) {
    // some code
    if err {
        st := status.Error(codes.Internal /*or other*/, "a message")
        return nil, err
    }

    return &pb.CustomerResponse{
        Proc: "",
        Data: "",
    }, nil
}
```

it will basically return either a `CustomerResponse` or `nil` which is totally what the parent function need.

Comment: But if GenerateCustomerInfo return any error then what status code should I return back? Do I need to define that too? You only showed valid case for that but for cases where it will fail then how to handle that. And client cannot be always in go as it can be c# or java based too.

Comment: yes you are right, this is implementation specific. Some languages will throw error (check: [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306467/how-do-i-get-the-status-code-ok-response-from-a-grpc-client)), some language will return a Status. Overall the framework is handling that for you, you just need to learn how to check errors for different languages.

At my work I have a server in Go and a client in Kotlin (throw exception) and I do not need to do anything special in the server, I just do everything like I showed here.